# How to update a table column based on output from a table-based function

Tags: sql-server

I have 2 tables:

**Course Table**

| CourseId | CatalogNumber | MajorVersion | CreatedDate |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | ABC | 1.2 | 1-2-21 |
| 2 | ABC | 1.3 | 2-2-21 |
| 3 | 123 | .4 | 5-2-21 |

**State Table**

| Course | MajorVersion |
| --- | --- |
|  |  |
| ABC |  |

For every record in the State table (tens of thousands), I want to populate the latest version from the Course table.

I created a table-based function to get the latest version:

```
function fn_get_latest_major_course
(
    @course nvarchar(50) 
)
returns table
as
return
(
    select top(1) [c].[CourseID], c.[MajorVersion] from [dbo].[Course] c where 
        ([CatalogNumber] = @course)
        order by [c].[CreatedDate] desc
);
```

I'm trying to move the data with this query, passing in the Course column for each State record to the table-based function to pull-back the MajorVersion

```
update State set MajorVersion = (select MajorVersion from fn_get_latest_major_course(Course))
```

But when I run this query I get this error:

*Column name or number of supplied values does not match table definition.*

This works just fine.

```
declare @catalogNumber nvarchar(50) = 'ABC'
select * from fn_get_latest_major_course(@catalogNumber)
```

So how do I, for every row in a table, call a table-based function and use the output to update one or more columns?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would use CROSS APPLY to run your function for each row in State.  It's like doing a JOIN on the results of the function.

```
UDPATE s
SET s.MajorVersion = f.MajorVersion
FROM State s
CROSS APPLY fn_get_latest_major_course(course) f;
```

Note that this works in your case because your function is returning only a single row.  If your function returned more than one row this would potentially blow up quickly.